# Debugging a button's function in an ASP.Net MVC web app - a 101 question from a newbie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I'm new to development and attempting to debug an issue.  I'm at the public url of one of our MVC web apps.  I click a button called Execute.  Doing so is supposed to write records to a database table, but it does not.  This button worked a couple months ago, but today I got word from a user that it's no longer writing records to our database.  So I'm tasked with trying to determine what's going on.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Clicked on the Execute button while watching the Console and Network tabs of the Developer Tools in Chrome to determine that pushing the button is actually doing *anything* at all.  It is.
2. Inspect the element of the Execute button to see what it's function is called.
3. Open the solution for the web app in Visual Studio 2017, and search for the function name from step 2.

From step 3, I found it in 4 files in the solution:

```
\src\Application.ConfigurationUi\wwwroot\js\Controllers\SailController.js
\src\Application.ConfigurationUi\Controllers\SailsController.cs
\src\Application.ConfigurationUi\scripts\Controllers\SailController.ts
\src\Application.ConfigurationUi\Views\Sails\Index.cshtml
```

The last one is the the actual button itself so is not material to the task at hand, so it looks like the first 3 are the pertinent files.

Next, I made sure that I can run the web app in Debug mode, and that in doing so I'm pointed at the database in question.  I can, and I am.

This now is where I'm stuck: what to do next?  I know I need to put breakpoints somewhere, but I haven't the slightest idea where.  The breakpoints part is where I admit I'm lost, as far as where I would put them. Once I know where to put the breakpoints, I assume I will run the web app in debug mode, and click on the Execute button, observe what happens at the breakpoint, step through the code, and hope to stumble on an error of some sort.

Once I'm able to do that I'm sure it will lead to a new question for assistance on the error itself, but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it.  Right now, I just need to know how to get **to** the error.

EDIT: per request, here are the two code blocks in the solution that relate to the name of the button:

```
SailListVM.prototype.Execute = function () {
this.currentSource().getDetails();
var jsonData = new ScopePlanTestIM(this);
var s = new ScopeTestAjaxSettings(jsonData, this);
$.ajax("/Sources/TestScopePlan", s);
```

AND

```
 Execute(): void {
 this.currentSource().getDetails();
 var jsonData: ScopePlanTestIM = new ScopePlanTestIM(this);
 var s: ScopeTestAjaxSettings = new ScopeTestAjaxSettings(jsonData, this);
 $.ajax("/Sources/TestScopePlan", s);
```

Comment: Can you show the code for button... that would tell us what function it is triggering. Also, you need to tell us if there is any ajax call triggered by the click.

Comment: You need to first put break point in the Controller Action method where the data is posted on button click. Then you can trace down the code by debugging further.

Comment: @Hooman - post edited to include code.  It definitely appears ajax is involved.